# Code not working when copying and pasting into jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```py
def get_first_name():
    first_name = input("Enter your first name: ")
    print("Your first name is: ", first_name)
        
get_first_name()
```

When copying and pasting this into jupyter notebook, I get the following error - `SyntaxError: invalid non-printable character U+00A0`

Comment: You copied an invalid character. Looks like an UTF-16 encoded linebreak. It might not be visible.

Comment: It's s non -breaking space.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that when you define a function you need to use the return statement in order to actually store the name in the variable and then, finally, be able to display it.

So I would change your code in the following way:

1. Cut the print function and replace it with a return function.
2. Paste the print function outside the "def" and replace the first_name by get_first_name()

To sum up, the correct code would be:

```
def get_first_name():
    first_name = input("Enter your first name: ")
    return first_name
        
print("Your first name is: ", get_first_name())
```

Hope it helps!